# sklearn DBSCAN to cluster GPS positions with big epsilon

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gps, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I want to use DBSCAN from sklearn to find clusters from my GPS positions. I don't understand why the coordinate [ 18.28,  57.63] (lower right corner in the figure) is clustered together with the other coordinates to the left. Could it be some problem with big epsilon? sklearn version 0.19.0.   [image: Test cluster]
**To reproduce this:**
I copied demo code from here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html but I replaced the sample data with a few coordinates (see variable X in the code below). I got the inspiration from here: http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data

X = np.array([[ 11.95,  57.70],
       [ 16.28,  57.63],
       [ 16.27,  57.63],
       [ 16.28,  57.66],
       [ 11.95,  57.63],
       [ 12.95,  57.63],
       [ 18.28,  57.63],
       [ 11.97,  57.70]])

# #############################################################################
# Compute DBSCAN
kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 400 / kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=2, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)

# #############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently made the same mistake (using [hdbscan](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), and it was the cause of some 'strange' results. For example, the *same* point would sometimes be included in a cluster, and sometimes be flagged as a noise point. "How can this *be*?", I kept wondering. It turned out to be because I was passing lat/lon directly and not converting to radians first.

The OP's self-supplied answer is correct, but short on details. One could, of course, just multiply the lat/lon values by π/180, but—if you're already using `numpy` anyway—the simplest fix is to change this line in the original code:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, ... metric='haversine').fit(X)
```

to:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, ... metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(X))
```

Answer (score 1):

The haversine metric requires data in radian